# How to share code between Docker containers?

Tags: php, mysql, docker, nginx

I'm pretty new to Docker, and I have this task. I need to write a configuration for creating a container infrastructure to run a PHP application using nginx, PHP-FPM & MySQL. The code for the application is in a tarball on a remote server.

What I did so far:

1. Created the fully functioning nginx, php and mysql containers.
2. Downloaded the code manually, extracted it to a host directory and mounted to both nginx and PHP-FPM containers with bind mount.

This setup works, but I don't want to keep the code locally. What I want is to download it during the build step of one of the containers and use it. My first idea is to use a shared volume to store downloaded code and mount this volume both to nginx and PHP-FPM containers. However, if I do it from within one of the Dockerfiles, I don't have access to the mounted volume (volumes are mounted after the container is built). I can do it to the host filesystem, but this doesn't seem right. What is the *right* way to deal with it?

Comment: did you consider using github for storing your code.. so your container will fetch it from there.. when needed

Comment: first of all, it's a 3d party code. So I can't do that. But what difference does fetching from git make in my situation?

Comment: In CICD world.. thats what its done. Commit the code on GitHub and it automatically builds the container with latest code. Since you didnt want to keep it locally, i suggested to keep it on github.

Comment: check this one.. this has options for Private Git.. so your code can be safe and still help.. 
https://itnext.io/building-docker-images-from-private-git-repositories-using-ssh-login-433edf5a18f2

Comment: Hey @Hedin, did you thought of using curl or wget during build time to copy the tarball an do rest of your steps? Ideally you should do a curl to get the code, compile/build the code, setup config and run - everything in Dockerfile. You don't need to mount a volume.

Comment: hey @Saurabh, I do exactly that. Actually I found that the data is copied *from* the container to the volume, so after the container builds, it can be then reused from another container.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found that the data is copied from the container to the volume, so after the container builds, it can be then reused from another container.